# Can I right-justify a div element without using absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

At the top of my page I have a **div** that spans the page, and inside that I want the login form to appear on the right side of the browser window.   If I do this:

```
<div>
    (masthead stuff)
            <div id="topLogin" style="position: absolute; right: 4px; top: 4px">
                (login form goes here)
            </div>  
</div>
```

That works, but the height of the parent **div** is not computed to include the size of the login form.   I see a javascript/JQuery [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085931/how-to-set-height-of-parent-of-absolutely-positioned-element-to-grow-shrink-with), but before I do that is there a better practice for getting this done?

Comment: `#topLogin { float:right; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<div id="topLogin" style="float: right;">
                (login form goes here)
</div>
```

Edit:

In your case use a style sheet as recommended for re-usability across your site:

```
<style>
  #topLogin { float: right; }
</style>

<div id="topLogin">
  (login form goes here)
</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the inline style attribute. Use a stylesheet.

Comment: There are certain (very few) scenarios where you'd want to use inline styling. In this case however I agree with @Truth, and use a stylesheet for re-usability across your site.

Comment: Only if you are giving someone a specific snippet to inject on his page, which is obviously not the case.

Comment: @Truth point taken. I'll be more careful with suggestions. Sometimes it's easy to assume everyone is aware of such basic concepts.

Answer (score 4):

You can float it to the right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use float:right; and you can use padding / margin to work with your spacing.