# How to create centered image slideshow behind website content

Tags: jquery, css, image, slideshow

I'm trying to create a slideshow behind my website content in the following way:

[Mockup image.](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6558226/slideshow.jpg)

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="slideshow">
    <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="content">This is content</div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    background: url(images/pattern.jpg) repeat left top;
}

#slideshow{
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow img{
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
}

#content{
   width: 1000px; /* just for testing */
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 10;
}
```

I'm using the `jQuery cycle plugin` for a basic fade effect

Using the above, my `wrapper` `div` has the same height as my `slideshow` `div`. How can I make `wrapper` extend to the bottom of the browser window, while allowing `slideshow` to take its height from the images inside it? I'd also like to centre the `slideshow` `div` horizontally.

Thanks.

**UPDATE: Resolved.**
Thanks to @Alvaro

Here is the final code http://jsfiddle.net/r6JYr/5/

Comment: it should be `src=""` Create a fiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center the image horizontally you can set:

```
margin:auto;
```

To adjust the wrapper to be occupy the full height:

```
height:100%;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6JYr/)

Comment: I have edited your Fiddle code and there is error with center positioning images and also with wrapper pattern as it shows only untill image height   http://jsfiddle.net/r6JYr/2/

Comment: I don't see the error with center position in images. #wrapper can't have it's child height as said here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085931/how-to-set-height-of-parent-of-absolutely-positioned-element-to-grow-shrink-with .So to solve that, either #content must not have a height http://jsfiddle.net/r6JYr/3/ or try with jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/r6JYr/4/

Comment: I have created final code that works with Cycle plugin that i need. Thanks for help. Here is it http://jsfiddle.net/r6JYr/5/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to di it responsive, you can set a width of the #slideshow (or #wrapper) of say 70% then set a margin-left of 15%
(15*2+70=100)

Or you can set a pixel width of say 1500px, and set a left value of 1500px and a margin-left value of 750px, (as 1500/2= 750)

that would work.

You also have to set #slideshow to position:absolute;

And you can remove #wrapper

Comment: 'And you can remove #wrapper' - assuming you want to background pattern to be the full width of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

No no no, best is to give the outer container a specific width, set it's left and right margin to auto and then workout the rest. Have a look at this:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<style>
#wrapper {width:600px; background: url(images/pattern.jpg) repeat left top; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; }
#slideshow {position: relative; }
#slideshow img {position: relative; left:0; right: 0; top:0;}
#content {
   width: 600px; /* just for testing */
   margin: 0 auto;
   z-index: 2;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px #000 solid;
   top: 0;
}
#slideshow {
   width: 1000px; /* just for testing */
   margin-left: -200px;
   z-index: 1;
   border: 1px #f00 solid;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="slideshow">
slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow slideshow 
  </div>
  <div id="content">This is content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
</div>
</div>
</body>
</head>
```